# Mac OS X set up to automatically group folders by date

Tags: macos

My brothers laptop (which I have now) automatically makes folders for each month of the year. As soon as I drag a file to the desktop the computer creates a folder! How annoying to have to click through EACH month to get to a file- no chance to organize things into your own files or it just creates more mess to search through -______________-
I don't see anywhere where it gives you this feature as an option so it must be something he set up himself?? Even researching it doesn't turn anything up. Need help turning this off! Thank you :)

EDIT: This website will not allow me to post images but the files go as follows...
2013 December> 2013 November> 2013 October > 2013 September> 2013 August.... etc. etc.!

Comment: Indeed -- this isn't a feature of Mac OS X that I know of. I think a screenshot might help... You can take one of the entire screen with command-shift-3 or select a portion with command-shift-4.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common possibilities I can think of:

**Folder Actions**

Open a new Finder window, right-click the *Desktop* folder, and select *Folder Actions Setup…* (possibly in a menu named *Services*). Uncheck *Enable Folder Actions* if it's checked.

**Hazel**

Open *System Preferences* and look for a preference pane named *Hazel*. [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) is a tool that automatically managed and cleans up folders according to user-defined rules.

Comment: None of the above!!!! I thought I finally had an answer, but it's literally like the computer does it without being told! I can't find any indication of anything being set up anywhere! I know it didn't even used to do this! I'm in school now & this setting is literally driving me nutsss. Please help! :O

Comment: http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/cleandesktop.htm this seems to have worked! I was able to put some folders on to the desktop and organize things how I wanted.. I hope it STAYS!

Comment: It is not solved, if anyone has any input please help me out.

Comment: @Rebecca Another option could be [maid](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid). Open *Terminal* and type `gem list maid -i`. What is the output? If that also fails, try opening the *App Store* application, and search through the *Purchases* tab for anything that looks related and is *installed*.